The member "XXXX" is already present
This is not a header issue.  I have a file that has the first 2 rows have the same info.

But I am getting a The member "935 Ocean Shore Blvd                    " is already present. Error.
How do I fix this?
I am running
$xl = Import-CSV -Path $csvfile   -Delimiter ',' | Export-Excel $xlsxfile -Autosize -PassThru 
$sheet = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]
Close-ExcelPackage $xl

Data:
Account,Name,Steet,ExtraAddress,City,State,Zip,Country,OldEmail,NewEmail,OldMobile,NewMobile,OldStreet,OldExtraAddress,OldCity,OldState,OldZip,OldCountry,NewStreet,NewExtraAddress,NewCity,NewState,NewZip,NewCountry,Date,
0000511111,A Margaret Tlaft ,935 Ocean Shore Blvd ,Unit 109 ,Ormond Beach,FL,3217 , , , , , ,935 Ocean Shore Blvd,Unit 109 ,Ormond Beach,FL ,3217,,,05/07/24, 

Each line is going to have the same thing on it twice. The same address will appear twice in the same line
Is there any other way to do this?
Output from
Get-Content -Path $csvfile -Delimiter ',' -First 3

Data:
Account,
Name,
Street,


That particular error indicates that the first line contains the literal cell value 935 Ocean Shore Blvd  at least twice. Can you share the full first 2 lines (as plain text) from the file? (FWIW it is categorically "a header issue" - something is going wrong while parsing the header line)

Please update your existing post with the relevant information

Please copy and paste the output of Get-Content -Path $csvfile -Delimiter ',' -First 3 into the question.

935 Ocean Shore Blvd ,Unit 109 ,Ormond Beach,FL,3217 is repeated twice in the same line?

Yes it will be repeated twice in the same line.

Okay it's obvious what goes wrong here: your CSV file doesn't have a header line. To avoid having PowerShell interpret the first row as a header, supply columns header names manually to the -Header parameter: Import-Csv ... -Header ID,Name,Address,...

Wait - does the first line of your file start with Account,... or does it start with 0000511111,...? Obviously can't be both

The first line starts with Account, Name, ..... So I need to specify those in the Import-Csv section?

No, if the first line of the CSV is indeed a well-formed row of column headers then you don't need to do anything - but then you also wouldn't be getting the error :) (I'm still waiting for you to post, as plaintext, the first 2 lines of your file)

Just updated it.  Must be something off with the header then.

I feel like an idiot....   I appreciate you all helping me through this.   The reason I was having issues.   There was an extra , at the end of each line. I removed it and it worked perfectly.

I feel like an idiot.... I appreciate you all helping me through this. The reason I was having issues. There was an extra , at the end of each line. I removed it and it worked perfectly
